# How to limit nginx autoindexing?

Tags: nginx, directoryindex

Is there any way to limit autoindexing to specific types?

What I want is to list only .svg files in a specific directory on my nginx server and hide other file types.

Answer (score 1):

The only proper way to achieve this is by generating the index file yourself.